# mocking consecutive REST call

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I have a service/dao layer. Service layer method calls 1st method of dao from which I get response and call the second method in dao passing some arguments including the value from the response of 1st dao method. I tried using mock but its failing with null pointer.
pseudo code is something like below:

```
Service{
serviceMethod(some_args){
response1 = dao.method1(some_args);
someItem = response1.get("someItem");

/* do some logic on someitem to create otherItem*/
request2.setArgs(someItem);
response2 = dao.method2(request2);
}
}
```

I have tried to mock as below but its not working.

```
@Test
        public void testPass(){
        mockResponse1 = new Response1();
        mockRequest2 = new MockRequest2();
        when(dao.method1(some_args)).thenReturn(mockResponse1)
        mockResponse1.setArgs(some_args);
        mockRequest2.setArgs(mockResponse1.getargs());
        mockResponse2 = new Response2();
        when(dao.method2(mockRequest2)).thenReturn(mockResponse2)
        service.serviceMethod(some_args)
        }
```

Comment: Is this a real java code or just a pseudo-code? I see that mockResponse1 is an actual instance and mockResponse2 is also an actual instance. If you are calling these mocks I was expecting something like mock(Response1.class) and mock(Response2.class). If you actual didn't notice this, then there is your problem.

Comment: `code is something like` may make it hard to spot the problem when you don't include the code for the actual mock creation (= `dao`) and also include the code where you inject the mock into the service class. Furthermore `mockRequest2` is not defined anywhere in your test code

Comment: updated the pseudo code

Comment: Please post real code and the stacktrace of the NPE

Comment: As you obviously can't provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this will turn into a guessing game. The NPE may be caused due to not defining `dao` as `mock(SomeDao.class)` and injecting this `dao`-mock into `Service` so that the invocation on `dao` inside the service method. As we don't know what dao is inside your service class during test-execution it may either invoke the real dao class or dao might be null and causing the NPE, besides not adhering to your defined rules.

Comment: the dao is injected as: @InjectMocks
 private DAOImpl dao= new DAOImpl ();

Comment: As you obviously try to inject values into Spring autowired fields, using [`@InjectMocks` might not be the best choice](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/) therefore

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `ArgumentCaptor` to get the value that was passed into `dao.method2(...)` and then make assertions on that.

For example, say I had this DAO...

```
public interface DAO {
    Response method1(Request request);    
    Response method2(Request request);
}
```

And this service...

```
public class Service {

    private DAO dao;

    public void setDao(DAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public Response serviceMethod(Request someArgs) {
        Response response1 = dao.method1(someArgs);
        String someItem = response1.getTheResponse();
        Request request2 = new Request(someItem);
        return dao.method2(request2);
    }
}
```

A test for this service could be...

```
import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private Request request;

    @Mock
    private Response response;

    @Mock
    private Response serviceResponse;

    @Mock
    private DAO dao;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Request> requestCaptor;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoServiceMethod() {
        // Set up
        when(dao.method1(request)).thenReturn(response);
        when(response.getTheResponse()).thenReturn("[ARGUMENT]");
        when(dao.method2(any(Request.class))).thenReturn(serviceResponse);

        // Code under test
        Response actualResponse = service.serviceMethod(request);

        // Verification
        assertThat(actualResponse).isSameAs(serviceResponse);

        verify(dao).method2(requestCaptor.capture());

        Request actualSecondRequest = requestCaptor.getValue();

        assertThat(actualSecondRequest.getArgs()).isEqualTo("[ARGUMENT]");
    }
}
```

The key line being...

```
verify(dao).method2(requestCaptor.capture());
```

This verifies that `method2` was called and captures the value that it was called with.

You then get the value...

```
Request actualSecondRequest = requestCaptor.getValue();
```

...and you can then verify that the relevant information was set...

```
assertThat(actualSecondRequest.getArgs()).isEqualTo("[ARGUMENT]");
```

Hope this helps.

---

For completeness, here's `Request` and `Response`...

```
public class Request {

    private String args;

    public Request(String args) {
        this.args = args;
    }

    public String getArgs() {
        return args;
    }
}

public class Response {

    private String theResponse;

    public Response(String theResponse) {
        this.theResponse = theResponse;
    }

    public String getTheResponse() {
        return theResponse;
    }
}
```